# Finding policy that is granting access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, policy

There is a resource (a Kinesis stream in my case) that someone is writing to. I want to find the IAM role/policy that allows the write to happen. How can I best do that using AWS web console?

Such problem seems like a common scenario to me, but unfortunately internet offers no help how this can be achieved.

Comment: Yes, generally that is not possible. IAM is not able to tell you all the things someone can do, everyone who can interact with a resource or everyone who can perform an action. IAM can only tell you wether a specific principal is able to perform a specific action on a specific resource given a specific request context (IP, date, ...). That is what IAM is designed for and designing a system that can do what IAM can do PLUS what you want is actually ***very*** complicated.

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but for the common scenario you are describing, the common solution is to use https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/

Comment: CloudTrail can answer your question regarding who performed an action but not who allowed it. And it will mostly only work for management and not data events, e.g. it works for DeleteStream but not for PutRecords: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/logging-using-cloudtrail.html